# An exe file created within the program is not updated in the same run

Tags: c#, csc

I create an exe file in my code using csc.exe in Windows.
The file is created and can be executed not from within the code.
However, in order to run the .exe file I created in this run, I have to wait to the next run.

**my code:**

Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csc.exe", $"/t:exe /out:{path}.exe {path}.cs");

Process.Start($"{path}.exe");

the file that is being executed in this run is the one that already existed in the brginning of the run and not the one I updated.

any advice?

Comment: You are not waiting for the process to finish before running the exe so you are getting the old results.

Comment: You never wait for the started process to actually finish.